# Ruby On Rails - :layout => false does not work on Apache2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, layout, partial-views, render

I have a method called by AJAX:

```
def showplain
    .............
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { render :layout => false, :partial => "content"}
    end
end
```

This works in Webrick, but causes an error on Apache2 + Phusion Passenger.

Error is:

ActionView::MissingTemplate (Missing template myitems/showplain)

If I create the showplain.html.erb:

```
<%= render :layout => false, :partial => "content" %>
```

It displays me full page, WITH layout, in AJAX frame.

It seems to ignore :layout => false parameter. How to make it display partial without layout?

```
match 'myitems/showplain' => 'myitems#showplain', :via => :get
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was an exception occuring BEFORE it came to render.

I wrote

```
begin
  .........
rescue => ex
  .........
end
render :layout => false, :partial => "content"
```

deleted showplain.html.erb, and everything works now.

Answer (score 0):

You speek about AJAX. To respond to ajax request you need to use the js format to respond to your app.

```
def showplain
    .............
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { render :layout => false, :partial => "content"}
      format.js { render :layout => false, :partial => "content"}
    end
end
```

And you call your route with the js format.

I hope it helps

Comment: Isn't .js reserved for JavaScript? I want the method return part of HTML code, and it worked with Webrick.